# Issues while export html table to excel

Tags: php, excel

Hi I am going to Export my html form to excel

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callexports()
{
var tabdata=document.getElementById("tabledata").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("tableval").value=tabdata;
document.getElementById("sendtable").submit();
}
</script>

<form id="sendtable" action="exportexcel.php" method="post">
<input type="button" name="Export Excel"
 value="Export Excel" onclick="callexports();"/>
<div id="tabledata">
<table  border='1'>
<tr >
    <th style="background-color:yellow;">Sno</th>
<th style="background-color:yellow;">Name</th>
<th style="background-color:yellow;">Marks</th>
<th style="background-color:yellow;">Age : Age Testing </th>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Anvesh</td><td>90</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Kapil</td><td>80</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Mahesh</td><td>70</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Sravan</td><td>90</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'>Total</td><td>330</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="tableval" id="tableval" />
</form>
  **exportexcel.php**
<?php

 $filename = "Student_Info".time(); //File Name

$file_ending = "xls";
//header info for browser
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
Echo $_REQUEST['tableval'];
?>
```

Now it's working fine.But i have a doubt

```
 <th style="background-color:yellow;">Age : Age new Testing </th>
```

Here Age is My heading and  Age new Testing is my description. Is there any way to remove description from `<th>`. I mean i need only Heading and i want to remove description? Please help me?

Comment: You could use a regex to trim the description (e.g. pseudo code `enclose everything from : to <`)

Comment: You have 4 th but only 3 td below?